# Is it possible to 'emulate' a regular post that loads a new page in angularjs? or plain java as a backup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, model-view-controller

I feel I am missing something basic. I can make posts to my MVC asp.net server, that perfectly respond with the required response in json (shown below).

Now I wish to POST some JSON data to the server, and load a full new page (different url), instead of AJAX. How can I do that? I tried manipulating $location, or $window.href, but those don't seem to support POST.

For clarity: My user clicks, the data get's posted, and a brand new page (within my own domain) is returned. Like a regular  click, but then POST.

I wish to call my MVC Action as stated below from javascript, returning a full new page load; How can I do that?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Rule rule)
    {
        RulesFilter filter = new RulesFilter
            {
                Page = 1, 
                PageSize = 10
            };            
        RulesModel model = new RulesModel {Rules = db.RulesMgr.Get(filter), Accounts = db.Accounts};
        return View(model);
    }
```

```js
 postAsync: function(address, model) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     var token = tokenstorage.getBearer();
     if (token == null) {
       deferred.reject("token expired")
     } else {
       $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: url + address,
         data: model,
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': token
         }
       }).success(function(data) {
         deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         deferred.reject(null);
       });
     }
     return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by injecting a `form` element into your page and then calling the `submit()` function. Here is an example:

```
var fields = {
    someField: 'hello',
    otherField: 'world'
}
var formElement = document.createElement('form');
formElement.action = '/target-url';
formElement.method = 'post';
formElement.style.display = 'none';
for (var key in fields) {
    var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.name = key;
    inputElement.value = fields[key];
    formElement.appendChild(inputElement);
}
document.body.appendChild(formElement);
formElement.submit();
```

This code snippet will submit the values in the `fields` object to `/target-url`.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, that you want to load a new page which has a different domain.

Suppose, if you want a `social share` feature on your site:

```
.success(data){
  $window.open(
    'https://facebook.com',
    '_blank' 
  );
}
```

If you are just trying to refresh your current page, in your SPA and if you are using ui-router, you can use `reload option` on your current state.

Comment: tx for the reply - I made my question more clear - I wish to navigate to another part of my site, using a POST (not a regular GET, url click). Basically removing the AJAX way of working from my code above

Comment: What do you mean navigating via ```GET``` and ```POST```. In SPA's you usually navigate when you get a success promise from get or post.

Comment: Do you mean to say, that you want to ```post``` to a server and when your server returns a promise from ```post```, it is then that you want to go to a new state or a new page?

Comment: One action: "Post data - go to new page". Similar to a form submit click. So no need for AJAX